# Python: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '808.666666666667'

Tags: python

I have a script that parses data from a csv file. The following line is giving me problems:

```
countData.append([timeStamp,int(my_csv[row][5])])
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '808.666666666667'
```

The line of the csv file is as follows:

```
2013-06-12 15:09:00,svcName,0,0,10,808.666666666667
```

I have tried running `int(808.666666666667)` in a python prompt and it works fine.

Comment: Run `int('808.666666666667')` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us what's `my_csv[row][5]` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From help on `int`:

> int(x, base=10) -> int or long
>
> If x is **not a number** or if base is given, then x must be a string or
>   Unicode object representing an integer literal in the given base.

So, `'808.666666666667'` is an invalid literal for `int` for any `base`, use:

```
>>> int(float('808.666666666667' ))
808
```

`int(808.666666666667)` runs fine because you're passing a float to it, not a string literal.

Comment: Thanks. The output of my_csv[row][5] was always a string representing an integer until today. I see that that was allowed, but not a string float/decimal.