# tracker invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

Okay I am trying to get the people and timestamp in a tracker but I keep getting this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 1389584370.27156
```

This is the code that gets that error:

```
elif used_prefix and cmd == "tracker" and self.getAccess(user) >= 1:
   try:
     if len(args) == 0:
        name = user.name.lower()
    elif len(args) > 0:
        name = args.lower()
    f = urlreq.urlopen("http://chtracker.info/index.py?output=json&x=page&y={}".format(name))
    data = json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))
    t = "{}, the last 10 people who visited {}'s profile are: ".format(name.title(), name.title())
    viewers = [(item['viewer'], item['timestamp']) for item in data]
    for l in viewers:
       viewer, timest = l
       t += "{} about {} ago".format(viewer, stamp.getTimeStamp(timest))
   room.message(t, True)
except:
   print(traceback.format_exc())
   room.message((str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

The error happens on this line:

```
t += "{} about {} ago".format(viewer, stamp.getTimeStamp(timest))
```

Traceback is coming from the timestamp2.py line:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "G:\Bots\Dragion Bot\Dragion Bot.Py", line 1159, in onMessage t += "{} about {} ago".format(viewer, stamp.getTimeStamp(timest)) File "G:\Bots\Dragion Bot\timestamp2.py", line 6, in getTimeStamp if int(t) <= time.time(): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1389584370.27156'
```

Inside the url are dictionarys with the same tags "viewer" and "timestamp" for example:

```
http://chtracker.info/index.py?output=json&x=page&y=mechabot
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '808.666666666667'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557870/python-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-808-666666666667)

Comment: Its not lol. I didn't make that one plus this one has json lol

Comment: Show us the whole traceback.

Comment: It's still the same problem.

Comment: problem is probably that you're trying to convert a string containing a float to a integer. What's the type of timest? what is stamp?

Comment: "timestamp" is time.time() if you go to the url.

Comment: The stamp.getTimeStamp is a string that converts time.time() to days, hours,  minutes, seconds.

Comment: Again, you have a string representing a float, you're trying to convert it to a int. You can't do that. See the possible duplicate question or the answer here for the solution.

Comment: Lol so if I do if int(float(t)) <= time.time() will it fix the problem?

Comment: Hello? Lol anyone there?

Answer (score 2):

```
 if int(t) <= time.time()
```

Don't call `int` on a string that doesn't represent an integer. If the string is supposed to represent a valid integer, something's wrong with the input. If the string is allowed to have a fractional part, as with the input you've shown, then don't use `int`. `float` might be appropriate.