# Error in python with: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a saving system in python by saving a value in a text file, but only strings can be saved into a text file so I want need to convert an integer into a string, when I tried the:

```
str(integer)
```

I got an error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is my code:

```
Number = 0

def Run():
    print ("Running")
    global Number
    Number += 1
    print ("\nIt has been run", Number ,"times\n")
    Save("Amount")

def Save(FileName):
    global Number
    File = open(FileName + '.txt', "r+")
    Text = File.readlines()
    Intergers_in_text = ""
    for i in Text:
        if isinstance(i, int):
            Intergers_in_text += str(i)
    Intergers_in_text = int(Intergers_in_text)
    Intergers_in_Text += Number
    a = str(Intergers_in_text)
    print (a)
    File.write(a)
    File.close
    print ("Text saved")
    Run()
```

Comment: You do realize that the numbers in your text will always be strings unless casted.

Comment: By the way, this will fail because of infinite recursion. You call each function within each other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '808.666666666667'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557870/python-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-808-666666666667)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

It means you are trying to convert empty string to int.

```
  Intergers_in_text = ""  # assign empty string
  for i in Text:          # iterate through Text
     if isinstance(i, int):  # It's never true, because you should check i.isdigit() - i is string always
         Intergers_in_text += str(i)
  Intergers_in_text = int(Intergers_in_text)
  Intergers_in_Text += Number # Intergers_in_Text are never initialized
```

You should check `Intergers_in_text` before `int`. Because Text can be empty. Like that:

```
   for i in Text:
      if i.isdigit():
          Intergers_in_text += str(i)
   if Intergers_in_text:
      Intergers_in_text = int(Intergers_in_text)
      Intergers_in_Text += Number
```

@Malik Brahimi noticed that your code also contains infinite recursion.

```
def Run():
     ...
    Save("Amount")

def Save(FileName):
    ...
    Run()
```

Maybe it's just incorrect formatting. Anyway, you can fix it, just remove `Run` call from save.

`Intergers_in_Text` are never initialized, I think it should be `Intergers_in_text`.
Also, I recommend you to read [Python Name Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

And I recommend you to read `Learning Python by Mark Lutz`. It helps you to write your code in python way.

Comment: That's obvious. You need to point directly to the cause of this error.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned the first of the numerous issues, can you be sure to highlight the other problems.

Comment: It's not obvious at all. If it was, OP wouldn't have asked for help with the error

Comment: What about the infinite recursion among others?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, I added as much description as could.

Comment: Satisfactory. Plus one for you.

Comment: I realize it is an infinite recurrence, but that was just for purpose of testing. Because when I done a forced Keyboard interrupt (this was before I asked the question) it was at 5169, yet when added up it gave 21 because it was doing each one individually, which is why it was a string. **I am also currently getting this error: local variable 'Intergers_in_Text' referenced before assignment**

Comment: @Paldox, you mixed up `Intergers_in_Text` and `Intergers_in_text`. The first 't' in `Text` words are different.